# Responsive Image Source (Sizes) based on Parent (Wrapper) Width

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

Given the following Code Snippet, my Goal is to achieve that based on the Parent Width / Wrapper, the Image (Source) changes accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Size</title>
  <style> div img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720"></div>
<hr/>
<div>1 (159px - different image):</div>
<div style="width: 159px;">
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720"
    sizes="
     (max-width: 160px) 160px,
     (max-width: 300px) 300px,
     (max-width: 768px) 768px,
     1600px"
    srcset="
    https://picsum.photos/id/275/160/90 160w,
    https://picsum.photos/id/276/300/169 300w,
    https://picsum.photos/id/277/768/432 768w,
    https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900 1600w
  "/>
</div>
<div>2 (300px - different image):</div>
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720" sizes="(max-width: 160px) 160px, (max-width: 300px) 300px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, 1600px" srcset="https://picsum.photos/id/275/160/90 160w, https://picsum.photos/id/276/300/169 300w, https://picsum.photos/id/277/768/432 768w, https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900 1600w">
</div>
<div>3 (768px - different image):</div>
<div style="width: 768px;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720" sizes="(max-width: 160px) 160px, (max-width: 300px) 300px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, 1600px" srcset="https://picsum.photos/id/275/160/90 160w, https://picsum.photos/id/276/300/169 300w, https://picsum.photos/id/277/768/432 768w, https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900 1600w">
</div>
<div>4 (1600px - different image):</div>
<div style="width: 1600px;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720" sizes="(max-width: 160px) 160px, (max-width: 300px) 300px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, 1600px"  srcset="https://picsum.photos/id/275/160/90 160w, https://picsum.photos/id/276/300/169 300w, https://picsum.photos/id/277/768/432 768w, https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900 1600w">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a different Image ID to visualize that.

I Read a lot of explanations regarding Responsive Images, srcset, sizes and it seems that the Responsive Image Source is based strictly on the vw (View Width) / em / rem / px or calc according Window Width. My goal is to load the Image Source based on the Available - Parent Element Width. With other words, I am trying to let the Image stretch to the possible Width and while doing so, load the proper Size/Resolution.

Is there any JS solution for that? Drupal CMS has an Extension (drimage) that provides / scales the Image according the necessary width. My Preference would be to use standard HTML/CSS Solutions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To load images based on the available parent element width while allowing the image to stretch to the possible width, you can use the `<img>` element's `width` attribute. This attribute specifies the intrinsic width of the image in pixels.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this without JavaScript, relying solely on HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive Image</title>
  <style>
    div {
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%; /* Make the image stretch to its parent element's width */
      height: auto; /* Maintain the aspect ratio */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1280/720" alt="Responsive Image">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

By setting the image's width to 100%, it will automatically adjust to the available width in its parent container, making it responsive without the need for JavaScript or the `sizes` and `srcset` attributes.

You can use this approach to load images based on the available parent element width while maintaining a responsive design.

**Another answer using JS and change iamge src at mobile size**

```html
<div id="image-container" style="max-width: 100%;">
  <img id="responsive-image" width="100%" src="https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900" alt="Responsive Image">
</div>

<script>
  const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
  const responsiveImage = document.getElementById('responsive-image');

  // Function to update the image source based on container width
  function updateImageSource() {
    const containerWidth = imageContainer.clientWidth;

    // Determine which image size to load based on container width
    let imageSize;
    if (containerWidth < 160) {
      imageSize = 'https://picsum.photos/id/275/160/90';
    } else if (containerWidth < 300) {
      imageSize = 'https://picsum.photos/id/276/300/169';
    } else if (containerWidth < 768) {
      imageSize = 'https://picsum.photos/id/277/768/432';
    } else {
      imageSize = 'https://picsum.photos/id/278/1600/900';
    }

    responsiveImage.src = imageSize;
  }

  // Call the updateImageSource function when the window is resized
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateImageSource);

  // Initial call to set the image source based on the container width
  updateImageSource();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am actually trying to display different images (sources) based on the width. The Images from the snippet are already stretched to the expected width. Also while using a CMS system with variable layouts, setting each combination would not be possible. Therefor I thought there should be a solution checking the available width and since teh Image is 100% stretched to this, the correct image size/source be loaded.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion in my previous response. It sounds like you want to dynamically load images based on the available width of the container or the viewport.